# How do I determine who the moderators are for Project Catalyst?

Tags: catalyst

I am trying to find out who to contact if I need to ask a question, make a suggestion or make a request about changes to a proposal or challenge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The members of the campaign team are listed at the bottom of the "about" tab for each challenge (Ideascale calls them campaigns)

e.g. for the "Dev Ecosystem" challenge, they are listed at the bottom of [this "about" tab.](https://cardano.ideascale.com/a/campaign-home/25939)